# In Angular directive the function $location.path always redirect to the default path

Tags: angularjs, directive

**This is some of my route**

```
  .when('/home/:type', {
       templateUrl : 'tpls/home.html',
       controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/excellent_comment', {
       templateUrl : 'tpls/gasStation/excellent_comment.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/push/BJshell-intro',
    });
```

**This is my directive**

```
app.directive('onBack',function($location){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
          element.on("click", function(){
            $location.path('/excellent_comment');
          });
        }   

      };
});
```

**When I click on the node that has the on-back directive, it does not go to the route '/excellent_comment', but it go to otherwise '/push/BJshell-intro'.
  It looks like the path is wrong but it's right.**

Comment: Could you please add element where you applied `on-back` directive.. one thing is for sure, you have to run digest cycle manually to see the changes in URL

Comment: Such like home.html ,it just a button like this : <div on-back>Back</div>, It just work wrong in directive .It works in controller

Comment: **I find where is wrong , in the element i write <a href="#"><div on-back>Back<div><a>, the href="#" change the route to dufault**

Comment: That's why i asked you to add element where tou applied Directive in a question..